# Trigger jQuery function when <form> content changes.

Tags: jquery, asp.net, triggers, updatepanel, dynamic-forms

I have a form that dynamically changes when a button and/or link is clicked, and I am using jScrollPane in a div located inside the form called ".softcontent".

When the content in the form changes the jScroll function does fire again.

So my question is: How do I trigger my jScrollPane function when the content in the form changes so the new content that fills the form have the same scrollpane?

**The jScrollpane function:**

```
$(function scrollbar() {
        $('.softcontent').jScrollPane();
});
```

Please let me know if I need to provide more or further detailed information,
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand "so the new content that fills the form have the same scrollpane?", but I believe it is irrelavant.

You bind an event to all form inputs: `$('#my-form input').change(function(){ ... });`

Just do whatever you need inside the handler. Details: http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: Yes, I would like to fill the new content into the same scrollpane. But your method doesn't seem to work.

Comment: what doesn't work? event isn't even triggered or is it something else? Little more info needed.